# How to disable Highlighting on sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-anaconda

I have sublime text 3 installed for python programs, with only three packages installed, those being Anaconda, package control itself and SideBarEnhancements. Also I haven't changed any config. It's incredibly annoying to write a code with everything outlined by this white rectangle. I have searched the interwebs for a solution but all I could find was simple answers on how to change syntax, nothing seens to help other than making the code colorless. Also with them, the scroling thingy gets really useless since I can't quite see where is the part where I want to go if it is a big program.

Thanks in advance. There is the image of what I'm talking about.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The marks you're seeing are the Anaconda package's Linting support telling you that it thinks that there's something wrong with your code; that could be something style related, or a potential bug, etc. While the cursor is inside of one of the rectangles, the status bar gains text to show you what the tool things is wrong, such as here where it's telling me it thinks there should be two blank lines between this line and the line above:

[image: Sample error]

If you use `Preferences > Package Settings > Anaconda > Default`, you can see all of the settings that Anaconda supports, and what their default values are. Somewhere around line 250 or so you'll see this:

```
    /*
        Set to false to disable Anaconda linting entirely.
    */
    "anaconda_linting": true,
```

Turning this setting off in your own Anaconda settings will turn it off. Although Anaconda installs itself in a way where you could just edit the file directly, that's not a good idea because it will be clobbered away if/when the Anaconda package gets updated.

So, you should modify the setting in your own custom Anaconda settings; the menu entry `Preferences > Package Settings > Anaconda > Settings - User` will open your user settings. If you already have some settings in there, add in this one and change the value. If the file appears empty, then add this to:

```
{
    "anaconda_linting": false,
}
```

As soon as you save the settings file, the linter will turn off.

Comment: Oh damm, thank you very much. I actually installed sublime to learn python without the features of an IDE, that linting is actually the in between. Thanks again :D