# Sublime 3 issue with highlighting

Tags: sublimetext3

How do I turn off the white highlighting of the text in a box in Sublime Text 3?
[image]

Comment: Did you installed the `Anaconda package` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable Highlighting on sublime text 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60893415/how-to-disable-highlighting-on-sublime-text-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These marks are introduced by the linting functionality of Anaconda, a Sublime extension which you most probably have installed.

To get rid of them, go to `Preferences > Package Settings > Anaconda > Settings - User` and change the linting settings there. To disable linting altogether, you can add:

```
"anaconda_linting": false
```

or to specifically remove the white text boxes as you asked, add:

```
"anaconda_linter_mark_style": "none"
```

For more inspiration on how to tune the appearance of the Anaconda linting marks, have a look in the default settings via `Preferences > Package Settings > Anaconda > Settings - Default`.